# Add view to ListView doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

I'm actually working on a chat activity,first i try to set a **layout** that contains just one **TextView** in my  **ListView** but it doesn't work .

**this is my layout ( message.xml) :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/message_content"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**This is my ListView(activity_chat.xml) :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".ChatActivity">

   <ListView
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dip"
    ></ListView>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="10"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:hint="Send a message"
android:id="@+id/newmsg"
></EditText>

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/newmsgsend"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:src="@drawable/send"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_weight="1">
</ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**And finally , my activity :**

```
package com.example.ismail.chat_test;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ChatActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    SetConversation();

}

protected void SetConversation()
{

  ArrayList<String> ArrayMSG = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayMSG.add(msg1);
  ArrayMSG.add(msg2);
  ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.message,ArrayMSG);
  ListView Lv  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
  Lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
}
```

my logcat show an error on **Lv.addView(v)** , don't know why , did i miss something ?

Comment: please add your error log.

Comment: With a custom Listview usually means you need a custom base Adapter to account for it. If you're just using one textView, I would just create an arrayList adapter and populate that.

Comment: Can you be more explicit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add `ListView`using `addView` method. `ListView` parent class is `AdapterView`, so you need to create adapter, set your data to adapter and then set this adapter to `ListView`. This tutorial will help you - [ListView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews)

Example for you:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map;
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Title", "Hello1");
myArrList.add(map);


map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Title", "Hello2");
myArrList.add(map);

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myArrList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
        new String[] {"Title"}, 
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
Lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also, your `LV` is null, because you set id - `android:id="@android:id/list"` and in code call `(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item)`. Add `android:id="@+id/list_item"` into xml layout.

Comment: i still got the error on Lv.setAdapter(myAdapter) ;

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.message,ArrayMSG); -  it is wrong, try the next - ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.message,R.id.message_content,ArrayMSG)

Comment: Both tested , nothing works :/ 
logcat:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ismail.chat_test/com.example.ismail.chat_test.ChatActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at : line 43 .
line 43 is : Lv.setAdapter(myAdapter)

Comment: Your LV is null, because you set id - android:id="@android:id/list" and in code call (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item). Try to add android:id="@+id/list_item" into xml layout

Comment: that's right ! please add this comment in your response , finally work